# Do we need to create subfolders in Documents before calling a writeToFile with a path that contains new folder?

Tags: ios, ios6, nsfilemanager

I am trying to write to the following path:

```
        NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *storePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/newfolder/test.jpg"];

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
        BOOL saved = [data writeToFile:storePath atomically:NO];
        NSLog(@"%c", saved);
```

Now, nothing gets printed and I can't see the file in my simulator. Is it because "newfolder" folder within the Documents main folder is not created yet. If so, is there a way to create it if it is not there yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, you must make sure the folder is created first. Use `NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:` passing in the path to the folder you wish to create (not the file you are trying to write).

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *storePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newfolder/test.jpg"];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[storePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
```

You should check the return value of these methods and handle any failures.

Comment: Plz help to create documents folder for adding images in iOS.

Comment: Thanks. There is a missing ']' after '[NSFileManager defaultManager' .